# require_once giving warning and fatal error

Tags: php, file, include, require-once

```
public_html > config.php 

public_html > A > test_file.php
```

in test_file.php code

```
require_once("../config.php");
```

works fine.
shows dynamically-related files fine (config.php) in dreamweaver

```
public_html > includes > classes > allclasses.php
```

in allclasses.php code

```
require_once("../../config.php");
```

shows dynamically-related files fine (config.php) in dreamweaver

when I include allclasses.php in test_file.php

```
require_once("../config.php");
require_once("../includes/classes/allclasses.php");
```

shows dynamically-related files fine (config.php, allclasses.php) in dreamweaver

test_file.php stop working and on browser shows

```
Warning: require_once(../../config.php) [function.require-once]: 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in .....\public_html\includes\classes\allclasses.php on line 11
```

using xampp as development server.

Comment: So is file physically there: \public_html\includes\classes\allclasses.php

Comment: test file is at public_html\A\test_file.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing includes inside includes it´s better to use absolute paths. So you can use the `__DIR__` or `__FILE__` constant to do it, just like this  in test_file.php for example:

```
require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../config.php'));
```

or just

```
require_once(realpath(__DIR__ . '/../config.php'));
```

Comment: still error Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\site\public_html\includes\classes../../config.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream:

Comment: its lacking of a slash between `__DIR__` and `../config.php`

Comment: well, this is a different issue. can you post the whole error message?

Comment: Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\site\public_html\A) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\public_html\includes\classes\allclasses.php on line 11

Comment: look, `C:\xampp\htdocs\site\public_html\A` is a directory. you won't be able to include directories.

Comment: but I am using require_once(realpath(`__DIR__` . '/../../config.php'));

Comment: try to exclude realpath function, like this: `require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../config.php');`

Comment: you also can try `require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../config.php'));`

Comment: Strange now no errors for include_once but not showing/importing variables from config.php in alclasses.php

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute url path instead of relative url path.

try this:

```
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/config.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you call something like `chdir()`, all require/include calls are relative to the directory of the called PHP file (here **test_file.php**). That's why the `require_once("../../config.php")` from **allclasses.php** throws an error.

In your situation, the simplest fix would be to remove the `require_once("../../config.php")` from **allclasses.php**, if it has no other impacts.

I would recommend to use a **[front controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern)**, to ensure that the called PHP script is always the same file (and include/require are always made for the same directory), and to do only once for all the include of the **config.php** file.

Comment: allclasses.php is important to have.

Comment: you mean it is important for you to call config.php from allclasses.php? why?

Comment: maybe you could ensure that when allclasses.php is called, config.php is always already included (should be the case with a front controller, but otherwise go for Jacobson's answer)